# Microsoft Based Touch/Stylus Input

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, touchscreen, pen-tablet

Disclaimer:It's my first time developing an app that will be on a tablet style pc.

The app needs to allow a user to write notes with either a tablet pen or by touch. This must be a .net app and may be on either Windows XP and/or Windows 7. **I am mainly tasked with capturing written notes from the user interface**, but I am sure I will be working on other aspects of the app.

I have looked into [Digital Ink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163869.aspx) and it seems the way to go, but I am unsure of how much support currently exists for windows 7 and how much support there is going to be for this technology in the future.

**My questions:**

1. Am I going in the right direction, and if not...is there something that would allow me to better accommodate this type of user input?
2. Does any one have other tips or good reference sites with good info on microsoft based touch and/or tablet stylus input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you plan on doing custom programming, you can check out the [Windows Touch API for Windows 7](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd562197%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Touch and Digital Ink both use C# and .NET framework, so I would imagine there is a considerable amount of support for Digital Ink in Windows 7.

Also, in the .NET framework, there's a Stylus class that tracks stylus coordinates in a text box, even if the stylus leaves the box and comes back in:
[System.Windows.Input.Stylus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.stylus.aspx)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft also provides the RealTimeStylus API, see [this tutorial](http://www.devx.com/codemag/Article/30352).